# Custom validation in HTML5 or jQuery validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have a field with id `max-number`

```
Max number:<input type="number" required  id="max-number">
```

and three or more fields input fields:

```
 Example 1: <input  type="number" class="min-num" data-slug="min-number" required id="example-num-1"/> <br/>
 Example 2: <input  type="number" class="min-num" data-slug="min-number" required id="example-num-2"/> <br/>
 Example 3: <input  type="number" class="min-num" data-slug="min-number" required id="example-num-3"/> <br/> <br/>
```

On form submit the number inside these examples fields should be smaller then the  field with `id="max-number"`

If the number in these example fields is greater than the max I want to show a custom validation message under `id="max-number"` that says `'The max year should be greater than all examples.'`

I tried to do this using HTML5 validation but I couldn't achieve.

I tried to do this using 'onblur' event.

```
 Example 1: <input  type="number" class="min-num" data-slug="min-number" required id="example-num-1" onblur="myFunction()"/> <br/>
 Example 2: <input  type="number" class="min-num" data-slug="min-number" required id="example-num-2" onblur="myFunction()"/> <br/>
 Example 3: <input  type="number" class="min-num" data-slug="min-number" required id="example-num-3" onblur="myFunction()"/> <br/> <br/>
```

Then I tried to create a js code that will be executed on all example inputs:

```
function myFunction() {
  var maxNumber = parseInt($('#max-number').val());

  var textInputs = $(':input');
  var datas = textInputs.filter('[data-slug]');
  datas.each(
    function (i, e) {
      if (e.value < maxNumber){
        console.log("000");
        $('#max-number').setCustomValidity('The max year should be greater than all examples.');
      }    
    }
  );
}
```

but this doesn't work and gives this error

```
 uncaught typeerror: $(...).setcustomvalidity is not a function
```

I don't know why I can't do this :/

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pinkx/Es6Nb/43/#&togetherjs=HKuAnz93uo)

Answer (score 2):

`.setCustomValidity()` does not belong to `JQUERY` but `DOM` use `$('#max-number')[0]` to use it it should work.

Comment: But now form is never submitted, whatever I write there..?

Comment: can get what you mean to say by that, are there any erorrs in the console or not?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `$("#max-number")` is a jQuery object and you're trying to call [`setCustomValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/setCustomValidity) on it. This function is a `HTMLSelectElement` function not a jQuery function.

You should use `$("#max-number")[0].setCustomValidity(....)`

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/4kht22n0/1/) is a working version of your fiddle

Comment: But now form is never submitted, whatever I write there..?